# Huggingface datasets ValueError

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-datasets, huggingface

I am trying to load a dataset from huggingface organization, but I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Couldn't cast string
-- schema metadata --
pandas: '{"index_columns": [{"kind": "range", "name": null, "start": 0, "' + 686
to
{'text': Value(dtype='string', id=None)}
because column names don't match
```

I used the following lines of code to load the dataset:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("datasetFile", use_auth_token=True)
```

Pleases note the dataset version = (2.0.0), I changed it to 1.18.2 but it did not work.

Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], which includes all relevant code (plus samples) to reproduce this issue. In the current state, the question is not answerable.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this error by streaming the dataset.

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("datasetFile", use_auth_token=True, streaming= True)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/3700#issuecomment-1035400186, you actually want to use `load_from_disk`:

```
from datasets import load_from_disk
dataset = load_from_disk("datasetFile")
```